# Web Firestore - Save Double value to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, double

I'm currently trying to save values on Firebase (on cloud Firestore).

My problem is really simple: I want to save Double values, but when a number is like 113 and not 145.3 for example, the value is automatically saved in Long.

This is a problem because my Android app crash because of that, and it's a mess to handle values that are Double and Long at the same time.

I tried:

```
parseFloat(15)
```

This is not working, if I do a console.log(value) I got 15 (not Double I
guess).

I tried also:

```
var number = 15;
var doubleValue = number.toFixed(2);
```

This is not working, value is saved in String.

This appears to be much more complicated to handle this on the web than on iOS or Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the official documentation regarding [data types in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), there are two numeric data types:

> **Floating-point number**: 64-bit double precision, IEEE 754.
>
> **Integer**: 64-bit, signed

And the solution to your problem:

> My problem is really simple: I want to save Double values, but when a number is like 113 and not 145.3 for exemple, the value is automatically saved in Long.

If you want to save `113` as double, then save it as `113.3` **not** simply as `113` because Firestore will see that `113` is a simple number of type `Integer` and it will save it accordingly. Always save the data according to the data type you need.

**Edit:**

Doesn't matter if you add, either `113` or `113.0`, the value is saved in the database as `113`. If you want to get it as `113.0` then you have to get it as a `double`. In Android, you can use the following line of code:

```
double doubleValue = document.getDouble("myDoubleProperty");
```

Even if the `myDoubleProperty` holds the Integer value of `113`, it can be saved into a double. A double can alsways hold an Integer while an Integer can never hold a double without a specific cast.

Comment: I was not clear sorry. If I have to save a value like 113, I would like to save it as 113.0 (and I don't know how to do that correctly)

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: So it's not possible to save 113 as a Double value from the Web ? It would be much easier for me

Comment: No, `113` will be saved in the database as an Integer but you'll have to read it as a double.

Comment: But if you have a Firestore query on double and you happen to manually save 113 manually instead of programmatically, it will be saved as an integer and ignored by query...bad...